# proving the injectivity half of de Rham's theorem by construction in degrees other than $1$ and $n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology

(This is a revision of a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186258/) I asked on MSE.)

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $n$, and let $\omega$ be a differential form of degree $p$ on $M$. Then we have (I'm pretty sure) the following theorem:

> **The form $\omega$ is exact if and only if its integral vanishes against all $p$-cycles on $M$.**

Call the second condition, about how $\omega$ behaves on $p$-cycles, "the vanishing condition." (Some people call it conservativity, but others -- or maybe just physicists -- use "conservative" to mean "exact," so I'll just avoid this term.)

I have two questions about this theorem. The first is about how the theorem is usually presented; the second is my real question, as indicated by the title of this post.

- FIRST: Where this theorem is stated in most textbooks, it almost always augments the vanishing condition by conjoining it with the explicit assumption "$\omega$ is closed."

But this strikes me as redundant. If $\omega$ vanishes on all $p$-*cycles*, then by Stokes $d\omega$ must vanish on all $(p+1)$-*chains*. I *want* to say that we can therefore infer closedness, $d\omega=0$, by a non-degeneracy argument, just as we can infer in measure theory that if the integral of a function vanishes on all rectangles, the function must be zero (a.e.). Paul Gross and P. Robert Kotiuga suggest as much in their book *Electromagnetic Theory and Computation: A Topological Approach* (page 9). (Note that although de Rham's theorem gives us a kind of non-degeneracy, it's not the kind of non-degeneracy I'm talking about here.) Is this right? I'm guessing it might not be; otherwise it's hard to explain why so many statements of the theorem are redundant.

- SECOND: Here's my real question. The forward direction of the above theorem is a trivial consequence of Stokes; it's the converse that is difficult and amounts to the injectivity half of de Rham's theorem, sometimes called de Rham's First Theorem.

However, the converse is of course very easy in the particular case $p=1$, by a routine argument shown even in elementary texts: the vanishing condition implies "path-independence" (equality of $\omega$ along 1-chains with the same endpoints), which allows us to write down a well-defined primitive for the one-form $\omega$. My MSE question got an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186258/proving-the-injectivity-half-of-de-rhams-theorem-when-p1-if-a-p-form-om/1187056#1187056) that shows something similar can be done for top-degree forms.

My question is: why can't we (or can we?) emulate this argument and write down an explicit primitive when the degree is not 1 or $n$?

The usual approaches to proving de Rham's theorem rely very heavily on technical algebraic machinery (either that of sheaf theory, as Warner does it, or open-set induction, as Breton does it), and we lose the direct, constructive geometric approach that we carry out for degree 1. In other words: in degree 1, exactness follows from the construction of a primitive, but for other degrees, it only pops out of a long and abstract algebraic argument. The "idea" of the former proof is obvious; the "idea" of the latter is obscure and hard to summarize or sloganize. (Of course, the Poincaré lemma gives similar constructive arguments -- rather intuitive and easily paraphrasable -- for arbitrary degree, but they only work because of contractibility.)

Does there exist a more constructive, geometric approach for these other degrees in general, and if not, is there any story to be told about why, beyond the fact that things get harder in higher dimensions? (The first difficulty, of course, is that we're no longer looking for a function but a $(p-1)$-form.) The jump in difficulty from $p=1$ to $p>1$ is remarkable; at least it surprised me. I was primed to think it wouldn't be too hard to extend the path-independence argument to one for "$p$-chain independence." But I suspect I'm just confused.

ADDENDUM: I've just learned that Whitney gives a proof in *Geometric Integration Theory* (1957). I haven't had time to digest his approach, but he has this to say:

> “It is habitual these days to treat algebraic topology from a very abstract point of view; using some basic properties of differential forms, de Rham’s Theorem becomes a corollary of general theorems. However, the difficulty of grasping the large body of theory required for this, and the resulting lack of evident geometric meaning, makes a direct proof by elementary means desirable. The proof we give is closely related to de Rham’s original proof.”

My question is in the same spirit, and maybe the geometric integration idea could help to answer my first question with the analogy to Lebesgue measure; perhaps someone could explain how Whitney's or de Rham's approaches are different from Warner's or Breton's.

Comment: One obstruction to an "easy" construction of a primitive for $p>1$ is the answer is only determined up to a closed $(p-1)$-form.  When $p=1$, this is just up to a constant, so we are done making choices as soon as we choose the value of our primitive at a single point.  But in higher dimensions, we are going to need to make a lot of non-canonical choices along the way to find a specific primitive.

Comment: Sheaf theory is a very constructive and geometric approach: in fact, it is just the right framework to patch local information concerning exactness (Poincare lemma in this case) into a global conclusion.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev: yes, I'm aware of this intuitive gloss on sheaf theory as supplying precisely the tools you need to paste local information together. But to my knowledge, the sheaf-theoretic proof doesn't write down an explicit primitive. Is that wrong?

Comment: I don't know, I never thought about this.

Comment: And that quote should date back to 1957. What would he think today of AT?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: I've just discovered that you echo the only reference I can find that directly comments on this dimensional discrepancy; Harley Flanders says "The result is hard if $p>1$ because there are many solutions" and then gives the usual explicit homotopy operator construction for the contractible case.